# ASP.NET - paging problem in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, paging

I have a list on the left side:

```
computers
mouses
keyboards
etc
```

I also have a gridview which appears when I press on one of them.

The problem is in paging: it doesn't appear

If I press on computers, it load a list on gridview and when i press
on pag number two in gridview, gridview dissapears, and if i press on computers again
i can see the list on page number two...

i want when i press on page 2, it load, i dont want my gridview dissapears...

properties..

```
AllowPaging=true
EnableSortingAndPaddingCallbacks=true
Sorting=true
```

do i forgeting something?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

        Dim tabla As New DataTable()
        tabla = daoprod1.busquedaxCategorias(Session("micategoria"))
        GridView1.DataSource = tabla
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

i had tried of many forms and it continue dissapearing

Comment: You should show us the way you control the visibility of GridView2. It's also impottant not to `DataBind` the first GridView on Postbacks, hence check for `not Page.IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a PageIndex changed event? If yes What is your code in PageIndex changed event?

Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged.aspx) link try the sample code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new datatable just add `GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex` and your grid like this

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        Me.bindgrid()
    End Sub
```